# Python(jupyter) for prime numbers

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
primes=[]
for i in range(3,6):
    is_prime=True
    for j in range(2,i):
        if i%j ==0:
            is_prime=False
    if is_prime=True:
        primes= primes + [i]

primes
```

The code seems logical to me but I keep getting a syntax error at the 2nd last sentence `if is_prime=True`.

Answer (score 2):

`=` is the assignment operator. For equality checks, you should use the `==` operator:

```
if is_prime == True:
```

Or better yet, since `is_prime` is a boolean expression in its own right, just evaluate it:

```
if is_prime:
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! New to computing and this totally slipped by. My code works now.